# EventHub send message, but System.Net.Sockets.SocketException on Application Insights

Tags: c#, async-await, azure-application-insights, azure-eventhub

I have this code below that sends message to azure EventHub, at first it works fine

```
public async Task SendMessage(string message) {
            
    var producer = new EventHubProducerClient(this.connectionString, this.eventHubName);
   
    using (EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producer.CreateBatchAsync()) {
        if (!eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(message))) {
            throw new Exception($"Event is too large for the batch and cannot be sent.");
        }

        try {
            await producer.SendAsync(eventBatch);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            saveLog(message, ex);
        }
        finally {
            await producer.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

but in Application Insights I'm facing this message exception:

> A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task
> or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved
> exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. A connection attempt
> failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
> period of time, or established connection failed because connected
> host has failed to respond

Exception type:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException

I've tried to add a ContinueWith (OnlyOnFaulted or OnlyOnCanceled), as below, to log it,
but now I get in the catch Exception (not in ExceptionHandle ) as "A task was canceled"

```
try {    
  await producer.SendAsync(eventBatch)
   .ContinueWith(t => ExceptionHandle(t, message), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
                }
```

How can I handle these exceptions that App Insights display?

Comment: I don't think we have enough of the code to offer thoughts.  What you've shown awaits all async calls (assuming `saveLog` is not async)    How is your `SendMessage` called?

Comment: I'd also strongly advise against the pattern that you're using here; the producer client is intended to be created once and used as a singleton for the lifetime of your application.   Creating a new client for each message that you want to send is going to put unnecessary pressure on the GC and not perform well.    There's also no benefit to using a batch for a single message.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle the task exception by using a **ContinueWith** (***OnlyOnFaulted*** or ***OnlyOnCanceled***) we can get this exception in catch block only. By default, if the task runs successfully, it throws Exception if the Task **IsFaulted** we can get the exception from **Catch Block**.

#### To fix this issue:

Use **[UnobservedTaskException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=net-6.0)** event which observe the Task Exceptions and it doesn't terminate by default. The exception can be **handled by the runtime**.